# onSessionEnd apparently not firing

Tags: coldfusion

I have an INSERT INTO Logfile in onSessionStart, and an UPDATE in onSessionEnd.
I've test it manually by calling onSessionEnd from elsewhere within the Application.cfc, so I know that it is working.

But that's the only time it's ever fired.

I wonder if onSessionEnd is never being fired.

Comment: What version of CF?  Have you tried lowering the session timeout and starting a session and doing a simple <cflog /> within the onSessionEnd to see if its getting called?

Comment: Please post your code from onSessionEnd()

Comment: Post your `Application.cfc` code please.

Comment: It may be running, but throwing an error, since onSessionEnd could potentially not have access to variables that you're using. As the others said, post your code and we'll look. Add a `<cflog />` tag in there as well to see if you can get data to the ColdFusion logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got enough upvotes on my comment, I figured I'd make it an answer for how to debug `onSessionEnd` methods.

First off, you need to remember that if you call onSessionEnd directly, it's being called during a regular request context. This means it has access to variables that it won't normally have access to if it's being called during the regular session end. This means that testing "manually by calling onSessionEnd" isn't a valid way to test the method.

To that end, the only way to reliably debug an `onSessionEnd` method is with judicious use of the `cflog` tag. You need to add cflog entries to flag when the method runs, you need to have error catching, to log errors or dump out `cfcatch` scopes to a file for review. You also need to make sure that anything you're referencing in the method is passed in via the `SessionScope` and `ApplicationScope` arguments, and that you're not referencing any scopes other than `Arguments` and `Server`. See [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=AppEvents_11.html) for reference.

Hopefully that helps you find the source of your issue.

Comment: Oh!  Thanks Dan (and all) for the comments!  I was using a session variable and needed to use a SessionScope variable.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'd add that you even can't call other Application.cfc functions from within onSessionEnd method.